# IDM show .TS files to download instead of flv or mp4

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

IDM behaves like this only in Chrome, but in Firefox it works perfectly. In Firefox, the number of connections are low due to which downloading speed is very low. The problem is only with video files from Dailymotion or Youtube